# Forcing specific data types as arguments to a function

Tags: r

I was just wondering if there was a way to force a function to only accept certain data types, without having to check for it within the function; or, is this not possible because R's type-checking is done at runtime (as opposed to those programming languages, such as Java, where type-checking is done during compilation)?

For example, in Java, you have to specify a data type:

```
class t2 {
    public int addone (int n) {
        return n+1;
    }
}
```

In R, a similar function might be

```
addone <- function(n)
{
    return(n+1)
}
```

but if a vector is supplied, a vector will (obviously) be returned.  If you only want a single integer to be accepted, then is the only way to do to have a condition within the function, along the lines of

```
addone <- function(n)
{
  if(is.vector(n) && length(n)==1)
  {
    return(n+1)
  } else
  {
    return ("You must enter a single integer")
  }
}
```

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: As a code style point, in the case where you don't have a scalar number, you probably want to throw an error (with `stop` or `stopifnot`) or give a warning (with `warning`) rather than just returning a string.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is entirely possible using S3 classes.  Your example is somewhat contrived in the context or R, since I can't think of a practical reason why one would want to create a class of a single value.  Nonetheless, this is possible.  As an added bonus, I demonstrate how the function addone can be used to add the value of one to numeric vectors (trivial) and character vectors (so A turns to B, etc.):

Start by creating a generic S3 method for `addone`, utlising the S3 despatch mechanism `UseMethod`:

```
addone <- function(x){
  UseMethod("addone", x)
}
```

Next, create the contrived class `single`, defined as the first element of whatever is passed to it:

```
as.single <- function(x){
  ret <- unlist(x)[1]
  class(ret) <- "single"
  ret
}
```

Now create methods to handle the various classes.  The default method will be called unless a specific class is defined:

```
addone.default <- function(x) x + 1
addone.character <- function(x)rawToChar(as.raw(as.numeric(charToRaw(x))+1))
addone.single <- function(x)x + 1
```

Finally, test it with some sample data:

```
addone(1:5)
[1] 2 3 4 5 6

addone(as.single(1:5))
[1] 2
attr(,"class")
[1] "single"

addone("abc")
[1] "bcd"
```

---

Some additional information:

1. Hadley's [devtools wiki](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki) is a valuable source of information on all things, including [the S3 object system](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/S3).
2. The S3 method doesn't provide strict typing.  It can quite easily be abused.  For stricter object orientation, have a look at [S4 classes](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/S4), [reference based classes](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/R5)or the [proto package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/proto/index.html) for Prototype object-based programming.

Comment: Yeah, S3 classes only handle the first argument. ...and `single` was probably not the best name - there already is a `single` class (single precision floats) with `as.single` etc - but it's deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

You could write a wrapper like the following:

```
check.types = function(classes, func) {
    n = as.name

    params = formals(func)
    param.names = lapply(names(params), n)

    handler = function() { }
    formals(handler) = params

    checks = lapply(seq_along(param.names), function(I) {
        as.call(list(n('assert.class'), param.names[[I]], classes[[I]]))
    })
    body(handler) = as.call(c(
        list(n('{')),
        checks,
        list(as.call(list(n('<-'), n('.func'), func))),
        list(as.call(c(list(n('.func')), lapply(param.names, as.name))))
    ))

    handler
}

assert.class = function(x, cls) {
    stopifnot(cls %in% class(x))
}
```

And use it like

```
f = check.types(c('numeric', 'numeric'), function(x, y) {
    x + y
})

> f(1, 2)
[1] 3

> f("1", "2")
Error: cls %in% class(x) is not TRUE
```

Made somewhat inconvenient by R not having decorators. This is kind of hacky
and it suffers from some serious problems:

1. You lose lazy evaluation, because you must evaluate an argument to determine
   its type.
2. You still can't check the types until call time; real static type checking
   lets you check the types even of a call that never actually happens.

Since R uses lazy evaluation, (2) might make type checking not very useful,
because the call might not actually occur until very late, or never.

The answer to (2) would be to add static type information. You could probably
do this by transforming expressions, but I don't think you want to go there.

Answer (score 5):

I've found stopifnot() to be highly useful for these situations as well.

```
x <- function(n) { 
stopifnot(is.vector(n) && length(n)==1)
print(n)
}
```

The reason it is so useful is because it provides a pretty clear error message to the user if the condition is false.

Comment: Note that this could be written `stopifnot(is.vector(n), length(n) == 1)` and that would have the advantage that if it fails then which of the two conditions that failed would be shown as part of the error message.

Comment: Touche, I always forget that it's stop if not ... conditions are true.