# Typing function arguments in R?

Tags: r

I wrote the following snippet of code:

```
b=function(x=numeric()){print(x)}
```

What does `x=numeric()` do?

`b('i')` and `b(3)` both produce the correct output.

Thanks!

Comment: what output does `b()` give you? ;)

Answer (score 9):

You are specifying a default argument of `numeric()`, which I believe is just a numeric vector.

Thus, if you call the function with no arguments, that parameter will default to `numeric()`.

If your question is about how to force arguments to be a particular type (as your title implies), then you want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139778/forcing-specific-data-types-as-arguments-to-a-function).

Comment: Ok, thanks! So basically one can complete override it?

Comment: @monkeybiz7, Yes, the default parameter does not impose a type restriction.